# SharePoint web part not displaying for site readers

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2010

I've built a custom SharePoint 2010 web part and deployed it to the home page of a publishing site. It's a very simple web part that just displays items from a SP list in a drop down list. The web part works fine if I'm logged in as a site owner or a member but not if I'm just a reader. The web part doesn't render at all to readers. I don't get any of the web part chrome or title, just nothing. I have other web parts (out-of-box ones) in the same zone that are displaying fine so it's not an issue of the whole zone not displaying.

As a reader, I can still view the list directly so it doesn't appear to be a problem with list permissions.

My web parts are being deployed as a farm solution, not sand-boxed and the assembly is being deployed to the GAC.

I feel like I must be missing something simple here but I'm stumped. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you save / Check in the page after editing?

Regards,
Faiz

Answer (score 0):

You may have to actually publish the page for a reader to see it